# special Characters in DB query is failing

Tags: mysql, sql

I had created a db named as Suri's _DB and had below query is failing when executed. If the db name is given without single quote the query is executing successfully.
The query is

```
 USE [master];

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE [Id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_filegroups'))

BEGIN    
DROP TABLE #tmp_filegroups    
END

CREATE TABLE #tmp_filegroups
(
[DbName] nvarchar(128),
[DbId] int,
[GroupName] nvarchar(128),
[GroupId] int,
[IsFileStream] bit
)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE [Id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_dbandlogfiles'))
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #tmp_dbandlogfiles
END

CREATE TABLE #tmp_dbandlogfiles
(
[DbName] nvarchar(128),
[DbId] int,
[GroupId] int,
[Name] nvarchar(128),
[FileName] nvarchar(260),
[Size] float,
[IsReadOnlyMedia] bit,
[IsReadOnly] bit,
[IsOffline] bit,
[IsSparse] bit,
[IsPrimaryFile] bit,
[SpaceUsed] float,
[FileType] int
)    
    
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE [Id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_fulltextcatalogfiles'))    
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #tmp_fulltextcatalogfiles
END

CREATE TABLE #tmp_fulltextcatalogfiles
(
[DbName] nvarchar(128),
[DbId] int,
[Name] nvarchar(128),
[Path] nvarchar(260)
)

DECLARE @DB NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @DBID int
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Databases CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT name,dbid FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name in (N'Suri''s _DB')

OPEN Databases

FETCH NEXT FROM Databases INTO @DB, @DBID

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''' + @DB + ''' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],s.name as [GroupName],s.data_space_id as [GroupId], CAST(case s.type when ''FD'' then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsFileStream] FROM sys.filegroups as s ORDER by [GroupId] ASC'

INSERT INTO #tmp_filegroups execute(@CMD)

SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''' + @DB + ''' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],s.data_space_id as [GroupId],s.name AS [Name],s.physical_name AS [FileName],s.size * CONVERT(float,8) AS [Size],s.is_media_read_only AS [IsReadOnlyMedia],s.is_read_only AS [IsReadOnly],CAST(case s.state when 6 then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsOffline],s.is_sparse AS [IsSparse],CAST(CASE s.file_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsPrimaryFile],CAST(fileproperty(s.name,''SpaceUsed'') AS float) * CONVERT(float,8) AS [SpaceUsed], Type AS [FileType] FROM sys.database_files as s'

INSERT INTO #tmp_dbandlogfiles execute(@CMD)



SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''' + @DB + ''' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],cat.name as [Name],cat.path as [Path] FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS cat ORDER by [Name] ASC'

INSERT INTO #tmp_fulltextcatalogfiles execute(@CMD)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRMESS
END CATCH

FETCH NEXT FROM Databases INTO @DB, @DBID

END

CLOSE Databases

DEALLOCATE Databases

select [DbName],[DbId],[GroupName],[GroupId],[IsFileStream] from #tmp_filegroups

DROP TABLE #tmp_filegroups
```

Why this is failing?

I tried escaping the single quotes

Comment: 'Can you suggest me on this why it is failing ? 'Because this is sql-server code you are trying to run in mysql? Or is the tag incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the `sql` query string, the dbname's single quote is not terminated. Replace any single quotes to 2 single quotes to terminate the character.

```
SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''[' + replace(@DB, '''', '''''') + ']'' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],s.name as [GroupName],s.data_space_id as [GroupId], CAST(case s.type when ''FD'' then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsFileStream] FROM sys.filegroups as s ORDER by [GroupId] ASC'

INSERT INTO #tmp_filegroups execute(@CMD)

SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''[' + replace(@DB, '''', '''''') + ']'' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],s.data_space_id as [GroupId],s.name AS [Name],s.physical_name AS [FileName],s.size * CONVERT(float,8) AS [Size],s.is_media_read_only AS [IsReadOnlyMedia],s.is_read_only AS [IsReadOnly],CAST(case s.state when 6 then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsOffline],s.is_sparse AS [IsSparse],CAST(CASE s.file_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsPrimaryFile],CAST(fileproperty(s.name,''SpaceUsed'') AS float) * CONVERT(float,8) AS [SpaceUsed], Type AS [FileType] FROM sys.database_files as s'

INSERT INTO #tmp_dbandlogfiles execute(@CMD)

SELECT @CMD = 'use ' + '[' + @DB + ']' + '; select N''[' + replace(@DB, '''', '''''') + ']'' as [DbName],' + CAST(@DBID as varchar(30)) + ' as [DbId],cat.name as [Name],cat.path as [Path] FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS cat ORDER by [Name] ASC'

INSERT INTO #tmp_fulltextcatalogfiles execute(@CMD)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Ed Bangga , If we replace it is fetching the db file but it is failing for all the db name as in the code some where they are comparing the db file names. because after this replace db name is coming with square brackets. example [db], so it is failing. So, is there any solution to work for all db's.